# Render a React child component plus additional properties?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parent-child

The end result I'm attempting to create is a set of React components that a UI/UX designer can use like standard HTML table tags, with nested custom components:

```
<Widget>
  <WidgetHeader>The Title</WidgetTitle>
  <WidgetBody>{this.props.greeting} World!</WidgetBody>
</Widget>
```

Using the React "Children" references, it's possible for the parent `Widget` to render those child components, but the issue I'm running into is wanting to set additional props on the children as they're rendered (e.g. setting a click handler on the `WidgetHeader` or setting CSS classes, or passing props such that the children components know the context in which they're being structured and can have values filled in, like the `greeting` in the example). I can determine which child is the "header" child by:

```
class Widget extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let headerChild;
    React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, child => {
      if (child.type.name == 'WidgetHeader') {
        headerChild = child;
      }
    });
    return (
      <div className="widget-container">
        {headerChild}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

But by using the `{headerChild}` syntax, I cannot pass additional properties to it (e.g. `<{headerChild} className="widget-header" />` is not valid syntax).

The only way that I can figure out how to do it is to have a dummy "wrapper" DOM node around it in the `Widget` component:

```
return (
  <div className="widget-container">
    <div className="widget-header">
      {headerChild}
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

But that clutters up the DOM, and doesn't give the child any connection to which parent it's a part of. I could have the `Widget` component create the `WidgetHeader` component:

```
return (
  <div className="widget-container">
    <WidgetHeader className="widget-header" {...this.props}>
      {headerChild}
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

That gives great connection for the child to know which parent it's associated with, but the properties still don't trickle down. And then that makes it more awkward for the UI/UX designer, as there'd have to be some other way to mark up which child element is the Header (or pass it as a property, rather than a child):

```
<Widget
  header={<span><strong>The</strong> Title</span>}
  body={[<p>This is the</p><p>body.</p>]}
/>
```

So, any other way to render a component instance that's held in a variable with additional properties passed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass additional props, you can use [React.cloneElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement).

---

For instance, instead of

```
if (child.type.name == 'WidgetHeader') {
  headerChild = child;
}
```

you can write

```
const additionalProps = { foo: () => console.log('bar'); };

if (child.type.name == 'WidgetHeader') {
  headerChild = React.cloneElement(child, additionalProps));
}
```